# Python can not print specific values in a list

Tags: python

I've got a users' given interval of years (e.g. 1998-2017) and have to print specific value from list 'mlist' which contains any of the years in the given interval. And print the name of the book by index in 'plist'. 
The problem is that it can not find that specific year in the list but it is there by all means

Already tried to do that by making for loop with range (startingIn, endingIn) but did not help

```
interval = input("Enter the range: ") #User selects specific interval

startingIn = int(interval.split('-')[0])
endingIn = int(interval.split('-')[1])

for x in range (int(startingIn), int(endingIn)):
    if x in mlist:
        value = mlist.index(x)    #mlist is the list which has years of the books
        print (value, x)       #plist is the list of books' names
    else:
        continue
```

plist = ["book1", "book2", "book3"]
mlist = ["1935", "1990", "1980"]

It has to print the year and the book which includes in users' given interval

Comment: It would be helpful to see mlist and plist. Could you update your question with mock values for these variables?

Comment: If the user enters, say, "2000-2001", the code looks for `plist[2000]`.  Does `plist` really have thousands of entries?

Comment: If `plist` is the list of the books' names, then `plist[x]` is going to return the the x'th, where x is in the thousands. I doubt your `plist` contains that many entries.

Comment: @JohnGordon it checks between this range, so between 2000 and 2001

Comment: Use a dict: `d = dict(zip(mlist, plist))`. Then you can simply lookup `d[x]`. If there are multiple books published in the same year, building `d` is a little more complicated, but still easily doable.

Comment: Or use `d = zip(plist, mlist))`, assuming the elements of `plist` are unique. Then you get a list like `[(book, year) for book, year in d if year == x]`.

Comment: Your `mlist` contains the years in string. The x variable in your code is an int. This is probably the reason why `mlist.index(x)` does not return anything. Try `if str(x) in mlist:` or change the values in `mlist` to integers.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that `mlist` is a list of strings. But the `x` are integers, and `1935` is not `"1935"`, so you never get a match with `mlist.index(x)`. Try to convert `mlist` to a list of integers.

```
plist = ["book1", "book2", "book3"]
mlist = ["1935", "1990", "1980"]

interval = input("Enter the range: ") #User selects specific interval

startingIn = int(interval.split('-')[0])
endingIn = int(interval.split('-')[1])

nummlist = list(map(int, mlist))

for x in range (startingIn, endingIn+1): #no need to repeat int() here, and note +1 otherwise endingIn would not be included
    if x in nummlist:
        value = nummlist.index(x)
        print (plist[value], x)
```

This works for me. It prints:

> book1 1935
>   book3 1980
>   book2 1990

Answer (score 0):

`mlist.index(x)` returns an index of an element, so you would probably want to get the element using

```
index = mlist.index(x)
itemYouWant = plist[index]
```

btw:
You may not need the continue statement - It does nothing in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the structure of the `mlist` and `plist` lists but I suspect  you should `print(plist[value], x)` instead of `print(plist[x], x)`:

```
interval = input("Enter the range: ") # example "1990-2019"

bounds = interval.split("-")

for x in range(bounds[0], bounds[1]):
    if x in mlist:
        value = mlist.index(x)    #mlist is the list which has years of the books
        print (plist[value], x)       #plist is the list of books' names
```